# Zuul gateway at production

Tags: netflix-zuul, zuul-testing

I'm migrating my application to micro-services and also implementing zuul+eureka for gateway and service registry.
Everything works fine at local. (Able to access backend service using zuul).

When i'm deploying this configuration at server level for single instance of each client or multiple instance of a client at same server (zuul and client) working fine. **What shall i do in order to access a client service running on different server (Not localhost) using zuul url ?.** (As far as i understood till now that zuul used to route internal backend service).

Comment: To add do i need to use nginx for zuul inter client service access

Answer (score 1):

Hi, I have this configuration in the .yml

```
zuul: 
  debug: 
    request: true 
    add-proxy-headers: false 
  routes: ServiceName
  path: /pathMyService/** 
  url: https://www0.app.appcorp.es/widgets/register/pub/bff/baselegal/getBases
```

So, when from my localhost I call http: //localhost:8002/pathMyService/ internally netflix-zuul is redirecting to the property url (https://www0.app.appcorp.es/widgets/register/pub/bff/baselegal/getBases)